# What is the best algorithm to see if my number is in an array of ranges?

Tags: php, algorithm, function

I have a 2 dimensional arrays in php containing the Ranges.  for example:

```
From.........To
---------------
125..........3957
4000.........5500
5217628......52198281
52272128.....52273151
523030528....523229183
```

and so on

and it is a very long list. now I want to see if a number given by user is in range.
for example numbers 130, 4200, 52272933 are in my range but numbers 1, 5600 are not.

of course I can count all indexes and see if my number is bigger than first and smaller than second item. but is there a faster algorithm or a more efficient way of doing it using php function?

## added later

It is sorted. it is actually numbers created with ip2long() showing all IPs of a country.
I just wrote a code for it:

```
$ips[1] = array (2,20,100);
$ips[2] = array (10,30,200);
$n=11;// input ip
$count = count($ips);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    if ($n>=$ips[1][$i]){
        if  ($n<=$ips[2][$i]){
            echo "$i found";
            break;
        }
    }else if($n<$ips[1][$i]){echo "not found";break;}
}
```

in this situation numbers 2,8,22,and 200 are in range. but not numbers 1,11,300

Comment: Is this one two dimensional array that contains subarrays with length of 2? Is it already sorted? Do the ranges ever overlap?

Comment: are the array of ranges orderer like in the example?

Comment: Without further restrictions, you'll have to loop the array and stop on first match.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Nope, you can do better (logarithmic) using binary search as John R. Strohm and I mentioned in our answers.

Comment: @middus It is true what Alvaro says, note the "without further restrictions". Binary search is only usefull when the array is sorted

Comment: Yes, but judging from @Towhid's question it seems to be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the ranges in a flat array, sorted from lower to higher, like this:

```
a[0] = 125
a[1] = 3957
a[2] = 4000
a[3] = 5500
a[4] = 5217628
a[5] = 52198281
a[6] = 52272128
a[7] = 52273151
a[8] = 523030528
a[9] = 523229183
```

Then do a binary search to determine at what index of this array the number in question should be inserted. If the insertion index is even then the number is not in any sub-range. If the insertion index is odd, then the number falls inside one of the ranges.

Examples:

```
n = 20  inserts at index 0 ==> not in a range
n = 126 inserts at index 1 ==> within a range
n = 523030529 inserts at index 9 ==> within a range
```

Comment: that is clever, that might be the best solution but numbers are not in chain. I don't have 1 to 10, 10 to 20 ,...

Comment: do you mean that the ranges are not sorted low to high, or that the ranges are not mutually exclusive?

Comment: actually it can be used. you search for smallest a[i] (from) which is bigger than your Value. then if b[i] (to) was smaller than Value, then you found your value in a range inside array.

Answer (score 5):

You can speed things up by implementing a [binary search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search). Thus, you don't have to look at every range.
Then you can use [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) to check if the number is in the array.

I'm not sure if I got you right, do your arrays really look like this:

```
array(125, 126, 127, ..., 3957);
```

If so, what's the point? Why not just have?

```
array(125, 3957);
```

That contains all the information necessary.

Comment: his array probably looks like `array(range(125, 3957), range(4000, 5500), ...);`

Comment: @Truth I thought that `range()` will actually create an array as described in my answer!?

Comment: What I mean is, it's an array of ranges, not a single long range. But yes, you could simplify the range array to be like that. (Though it hardly matters for the sake of this question)

Comment: Actually, it does. It's more efficient to check if `min <= n <= max` than it is to check if `n in array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, .... m);`

Answer (score 3):

The example you give suggests that the numbers may be large and the space sparse by comparison.

At that point, you don't have very many options.  If the array is sorted, binary search is about all there is.  If the array is not sorted, you're down to plain, old CS101 linear search.

Answer (score 2):

The correct data structure to use for this problem is an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). This is, in general, much faster than binary search.

Comment: "This is, in general, much faster than binary search." How so?

Comment: I believe an interval tree has more relaxed requirements than what the original question is asking and is thus less efficient than binary search. An interval tree can handle overlapping intervals: (1,100), (50,200) while the original question seems to have no overlaps. (At least their accepted answer assumes no overlaps.)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the ranges do not overlap.

If that is the case, you can maintain a map data structure that is keyed on the lower value of the range.

Now all you have to do (given the number N) is to find the key in the map that is just lower than N (using binary search - logarithmic complexity) and then check if the number is lesser than the right value.

Basically, it is a binary search (logarithmic) on the constructed map.

Answer (score 0):

From a pragmatic point of view, a linear search may very well turn out to be the fastest lookup method. Think of page faults and hard disk seek time here.

If your array is large enough (whatever "enough" actually means), it may be wise to stuff your IPs in a SQL database and let the database figure out how to efficiently compute `SELECT ID FROM ip_numbers WHERE x BETWEEN start AND end;`.